# Symfony Twig template form redirecting broken

Tags: php, symfony

I've moved my public directory into `public_html`, while dependency and vendor are accessible in `public_html/core` directory. I edited index.php located in `public_html/forum` and changed Env and vendor path to the correct path. So, no problem here. The problem comes at form redirecting in twig template. it redirects to `localhost/login` but it needs to be redirected to `localhost/forum/login`.
Im using in twig the following attribute `{{form_start(formLogin, {'action': absolute_url('/login'), 'method': 'POST'} ) }}` tried everything and don't work :/. Is this a bug ?

Symfony 4.1 version i'm using.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Error is 404, normally. Because it redirects to localhost/login while the script is located in /forum directory.

And the core files are in  the `core` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed temporary the problem by placing index.php in the root directory of `public_html` in my webhost.
Added the .htaccess in the `public_html` as well and now it works good.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `absolute_url` in a wrong way.
Look at the [document](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#absolute-url) for reference.

If you are on this URL: `http://example.com/products/hover-board`

```
{{ absolute_url('/human.txt') }}
{# http://example.com/human.txt #}

{{ absolute_url('products_icon.png') }}
{# http://example.com/products/products_icon.png #}
```

If you remove the slash, it should work properly

Comment: Tried also with 
`{{form_start(formLogin, {'action': absolute_url('login'), 'method':'POST'}) }}`
And it don't work. Always it will redirect me to localhost/login where is not there the application.